# Manage cart session for mulipte users

Tags: php, jsp

I created shopping cart name of $_SESSION['cart'] and for user i created $_SESSION['user'].When i click on add to cart the same product showing to all the users. I want to know how to link particular user_id to cart Session. I'm beginner in php. Please help me.

Here is the code

```
if(isset($_SESSION["cart"]))
    {
       $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["cart"], "item_id");
        if(!in_array($_GET['id'], $item_array_id)){
            $count = count($_SESSION["cart"]);
            $item_array = array(
        'item_id' =>  $_GET['id'],
            'item_name' => $_POST['hidden_name'],
            'item_price' => $_POST['hidden_price'],
                'item_image' => $_POST['hidden_image']
       );
            $_SESSION["cart"][$count] = $item_array;

        }

    }
    else{
        $item_array = array(
        'item_id' =>  $_GET['id'],
            'item_image' => $_POST['hidden_image'],
            'item_name' => $_POST['hidden_name'],
            'item_price' => $_POST['hidden_price']

       );
        $_SESSION["cart"][0] = $item_array;

    }


}
```

Comment: If you are using the default session settings of php, that is not possible; a session is unique to a browser session of a visitor. What else are you doing, are you using a database to store the cart as well?

Comment: no, i'm not using database. How can i make unique session of all users

Comment: A session is always unique for every visitor, there is nothing you have to do for that.

Comment: So what can i do to solve this issue

Comment: any solution bro

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of not using 'session_start()' to initialize the unique sessions. Just add that before you use the sessions and you should be good to go.

Comment: should i use Session_start() for every page because i already used it in connection folder

Comment: KK i wil give my connection folder

Comment: <?php
ob_start();
session_start();
//session_destroy();

$db['db_host']= "localhost";
$db['db_user']= "root";
$db['db_pass']= "";
$db['db_name']= "oddball";


foreach($db as $key => $value){
    
    define(strtoupper($key),$value);
}


$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);



?>

Comment: Is there anything which is there before the output buffer? Because if a single piece of data is send before you have your 'session_start()' it will not send the cookies, thus the session will not work.

Comment: solve my issue plzz i have to give this project in 2 days

Comment: I also have other things to do, if no other user picks up this question it can mean 3 things: 1. Users think your question is poorly explaind. 2. Users think that you havent proved that you have actually tried to solve the problem. 3. You do not provide the required resources (code and such).